# Object Context disposed exception on a certain combination of records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm not able to identify any specific code for this problem, but I'll describe the setup and the problem and see if I can get any answers.

- User object, contains Profile record. Profile record contains Template record.
- On user login, I hold this user object in session.
- When I need, I ask about access rights from the template record.

This is working perfectly in MOST cases. I can login, works fine. Another user (set to a different access template) logs in and the first access right check fails because it reports the Object Context is disposed. I change the access template to the same as me, all works fine. I change my access template to be the one that's breaking on the other user and it works  fine. The stack trace doesn't identify anything else. The Profile record (also an associated record) is fully populated, there are other associations on the profile record that work just fine.

Summary;

Me without changes, works fine.
Other user without changes, crashes.
Me with same exact setup as other user, works fine.
Other user with my setup works fine.

I'm not sure what to look at, I can't identify any particular failing code so I don't think the method is bad. If I debug while logging in as the broken user, it doesn't break anymore.

Does anybody have any suggestions, advice or information I can provide? I don't know if it helps to know I'm using MVC3, but I've tagged it there just in case.

**Update:** Thank-you for the input. I have got a solution, but I can't explain it.

Table A contains association with Table B
Table C contains association with Table B (Table B has NO association with C or A )

By changing records in C, I could fix the issue, there was consistency in that I could change the records to match a broken user and my user would break. If I changed the records back, it would work again for me. My login process makes mention of table C, but does not set any data or change the behavior of the loading of profile from table A.

If I prevent the lazy load of B; TableA.Include(TableB) the problem goes away regardless of what is in table C.

Why would the lazy load work in some cases but not others? The records that Table C contained were all valid in both failure and success cases, and there was no direct change of A based on any query of C.

I know that the only way for someone to really have an answer to this is to see the code, which I can't share, but if anybody has any ideas or has seen this behavior before, I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: The exception means that your code somewhere tries to access the database (when you load the user, or the profile, or the template???) but you don't have a valid object context/database connection anymore to manage the database access. Are you using lazy loading? How do you create and dispose the context? How do you load the entities in question? Maybe you can show the relevant code for this part.

Comment: I do understand that the Object Context disposed exception means the connection is no longer available, and yes I'm using Lazy Loading in this case. What I'm confused about is that the behavior isn't consistent, it seems to change based upon who is logged in.Also, there are other associations, made in the same way that work fine. They're all created on the same context, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: How do you initialize the context, normally, you need initialize context per Http Request, if you use a static context, then it may cause you this problem.

Comment: I am initializing per request.

Comment: Holding an entity with navigation properties with lazy loading in session state doesn't sound good. I could imagine that you access a navigation property during the "second" request when you loaded the parent and put it into session state in the first request. Because you dispose the context per request, lazy loading wouldn't work anymore and you'd get the exception - unless you have already loaded the navigation property in the first request. Just a guess.